# CDF for uncorrelated bivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate

I have an uncorrelated bivariate normal process: $X \sim N(0, \sigma_1), Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2), \rho = 0$, and I'm interested in the distribution of $Z = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

I know that if I'm willing to normalize *X* and *Y* by their variance then *Z* has the chi distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.

But I am looking for closed-form expressions of the variance and CDF of Z that incorporate the difference in variance in the two dimensions.  I.e., without factoring out the sigmas, and knowing $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$,

- What is the variance of Z?
- What is the CDF -- i.e., Pr($Z \leq \alpha$)?  (I know this is also an elliptic distribution, but the general form for those is far too complicated.)

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form because the radial distribution is proportional to the Laplace transform of $\sqrt{r}I_0(r\tau)$ where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and $\tau$ is a constant (depending on $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$): this simplifies only when $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$.

Comment: Shoot, I hate it when these simple problems have complex solutions ;)  Can you point me towards numerical methods for computing the probabilities?

Comment: I use *Mathematica* for general-purpose numerical integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent random variables, then the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is say $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Given $Z = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$, you seek $\text{Var}(Z)$:

[image]

where `Var` is the Variance function from the *mathStatica* add-on to *Mathematica* (to compute the pleasantries), and `EllipticE` is the complete elliptic integral: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EllipticE.html

Here is a plot of the solution $\text{Var}(Z)$, as a function of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, as you desired:

[image]

For the cdf calculation, I would suggest that a transformation to polar coordinates should do the trick.

Comment: +1. The transformation to polar coordinates leads to the results I cited in a comment to the question.

Comment: @whuber The distribution of $Z$ is the [Hoyt distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoytDistribution.html) which can be written in closed form. The Mathematica reference also gives the moments in terms of its parametrization $q$ and $\omega$.